# Will Windows remove bundled applications when I factory reset it?

Tags: windows-10, reset

Last year I bought a PC with Windows 8.1 and a bundled video editor (Cyberlink PowerDirector), which I use.

I have just updated to Windows 10 and think now would be the right time to factory reset the OS, removing everything.

Will this also remove the bundled applications or does Windows 10 somehow know that these applications shouldn't be deleted?

If Windows will delete these applications, what is a legitimate way to get them back? I don't think I can get the installer without buying a new copy.

Comment: It depends.  If you want them then select "keep everything" if you don't want them then select "keep nothing"

Comment: I want to get rid of absolutely everything, except the bundled apps. As if it came from the shop, but with Windows 10 instead of Windows 8.1

Comment: Well after a factory restore that exactly what you would have, so then you would just select "keep everything" and you would have everything the factory install has.

Comment: Even though in the meantime I've upgraded to Windows 10?

Comment: If you selected "keep nothing" then those factory software installations will be removed.

Answer (score 2):

This is universal answer regardless the model of your PC. As [@Ramhound commented](https://superuser.com/questions/950432/will-windows-remove-bundled-applications-when-i-factory-reset-it/950487#comment1296241_950432), it depends on the option you choose. But if you are more likely to completely clean your computer,  you need to check one more thing:

- check if the installation media for the software can be obtained

  - at support location for your computer model at its manufacturer
  - at support department of your vendor

    - it is possible that they will forward you to some large-scale PC distributor which is in charge of the bundled software

This way, in many cases, I was able to get the installation media of most software coming with the computer. (Once even for second-hand computer.) Having the installation media, there is no problem to "get rid of absolutely everything" as you said and you can re-install the stuff anew.

So there is a homework for you: go get definitive answer ("yes" or "no") for your computer model from sites/people who have this information. Then you will know what is the answer and you will better understand how to continue.

Yet another factor is price and usfeullnes of the software.

In case of software like the [CyberLink PowerDirector](http://www.cyberlink.com/products/powerdirector-ultra/features_en_EU.html?&r=1) you can consider if you want to

- Get the bundled software again and know you will lose it when your computer 'dies' (bundled software is not transferrable). Then you will hope your new computer will have it bundled, too.
- Buy a full license which remains 'yours' on any of your future computers. You can simply install it to your new computer when you switch (& deinstall on old one). Some 'more friendly' licenses allow 2 simultaneous installations (on your laptop+desktop PC), etc.

With good software, I'm usually going with the second option.